# Adding new row of data to a jTable with a Button Click

Tags: java, jtable

I am trying to add data read in from a form into a jTable. So far this is what I have and Im not sure why it will not work. This is the code:

```
    public void fillTable(){
        String inputField1 = jTextArea1.getText();
        String inputField2 = jTextField8.getText();
        String inputField3 = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String inputField4 = jTextField11.getText(); 
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        int numRows = jTable2.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++){
            model.setValueAt(inputField1, numRows, 1);
            model.setValueAt(inputField2, numRows, 2);
            model.setValueAt(inputField3, numRows, 4);
            model.setValueAt(inputField4, numRows, 6);      
        }
        jTable2.setModel(model);     
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue=0" java.lang.ClassCastException:  my.rcs.accounting.DraftInvoice$5 cannot be cast to groovy.model.DefaultTableModel
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the exception being thrown ? Also, it look weird that you are looping over each row of the table but only setting the row at `numRows` (which will throw an exception BTW).

Comment: What do you mean by where is the exception being thrown? This method is called when a button is clicked. I still get the same exception even if I don't use the for loop.

Comment: I mean, which line on your code. My guess is that `jTable2.getModel` return a `my.rcs.accounting.DraftInvoice` and not a `groovy.model.DefaultTableModel` which result in an exception when you try to cast `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();`. You should try to use `DraftInvoice model = (DraftInvoice ) jTable2.getModel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you locate the code that *creates* your jTable2?
And also the exact import (=package name) you use for DefaultTableModel ?

I suspect the ClassCastException could come from this line:
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();

which begs two questions:

```
1) what table model was initially associated with jTable2, it seems to be some inner class my.rcs.accounting.DraftInvoice$5 and the question is - does it inherit from DefaultTableModel

2) What DefaultTableModel are you expecting, naiively I'd expect it to be javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
```

Comment: jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Description", "Date", "Qty", "Rate", "VAT", "Total"
        }
    )

Comment: ^^That is the model used when creating the jTable. This is the import code: import groovy.model.DefaultTableModel;

Comment: So you should import " javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel", not that groovy stuff...

Answer (score 2):

It's should be `i` instead of `numRows`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++) {
      model.setValueAt(inputField1, i, 1);
      model.setValueAt(inputField2, i, 2);
      model.setValueAt(inputField3, i, 4);
      model.setValueAt(inputField4, i, 6);      
}
```